# 'Cmd cd' doesn't switch to another drive

Tags: windows, cmd

I understand there are multiple threads on this topic, but all three I've found with hundreds+ answers didn't resolve my issue. Here is the output of different solutions I've tried.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Alle rettigheder forbeholdes.

C:\Windows\system32>cd J:\

C:\Windows\system32>cd J:
J:\

C:\Windows\system32>cd J:/

C:\Windows\system32>cd J:\OBS

C:\Windows\system32>cd /j j:\OBS
Syntaksen i filnavnet, mappen eller diskenhedsnavnet er forkert (Syntax error, despite path auto-completing).

C:\Windows\system32>
```

And yes, I run in Admin mode.

Comment: try   *"cd /d J:\"*

Comment: ARF of course the only thing I tried. I thought the /d was the drive, not an argument. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint for the future: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run the command with `/?` as argument to get displayed its help. Try that out with `cd /?`. See also the Microsoft documentations for the [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and [SS64.com - A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Comment: This question is clearly off-topic. See the [help/on-topic]. And since you haven't, take the [tour] as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RbMm answered in the comments:

`cd /d J:\` was the command I was looking for.

Comment: For any and all commands, read the provided documentation. `CD /?`